# Convert a Javascript object to a Json object without serializing

Tags: java, gwt

I have a java-script object (`com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject`). I need to convert the data in this object into a JSONObject (`com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`). How can I do this?.

I have tried this:

```
JavaScriptObject object=getData();

String json=stringfy((JsArray) object);  //done using native JSNI method

JSONValue jsonValue=null;

jsonValue=JSONParser.parseStrict(json);

JSONObject  msg=jsonValue.isObject();
```

The problem here is that I need to serialize and make a json string out of my data which is an overhead. Is there any other method to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JavaScriptObject object = getData();
JSONObject msg = new JSONObject(object);
```